# Preventing merge to create nodes

Tags: neo4j

Is there are way wherein I can prevent merge in cypher to not create node if its not present.
I have a query like

```
FOREACH(p in {props} |
   MERGE (I:Interface {IfIPAddress:p.OrigIPAddress})
  MERGE (I2:Interface {IfIPAddress:p.TermIPAddress})
MERGE (I)-[r:link]->(I2)
SET r = p)
```

where the props is a map of arrays.

In the first and second merge I do not want I and I2 to be created. Is it possbile?

Comment: Can you clarify a bit? When you say you don't want I and I2 to be created in the first and second merge, do you mean you don't want them to be created in the first two iterations of the loop?  Or are you saying you NEVER want the merges to create the nodes?  The whole point of merge is that it will create a node if not found or match otherwise.  Are you only looking to do match/update operations?  Or what's your use case here?

Comment: I cannot use a match in a foreach, it gives me error in cypher. My question is, Is there any alternative to Match here in foreach. Whatever I have read I have found that I can use merge but the problem with merge is that it creates Interface nodes if they are not present which I do not want.

Comment: s the goal to update the Interface properties and create the relationship in your query? Or just to create the relationship?

Comment: The goal of this query is just to create the link i.e relationship between the interfaces. I do not want this query to create any additional interfaces.

Answer (score 1):

Is it out of the question to iterate through the map and dynamically create a query for each map entry? I.e. don't do it in a single query but multiple?

Comment: Hmmm. Finally then I have to do it which will increase the time of creation. It would be gr8 if it could be done in one go as it will save a lot of time in creation

Answer (score 0):

You can't match in a foreach loop, probably because of the more basic restriction that reading and updating operations must be completed separately, see [docs](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/query-updating.html#query-updating-structure). There may be ways to make `MERGE` act like `MATCH` with chewing gum and duct tape, but it's probably easier to accept this limitation and run a flat query for each operation. Is there some other reason why you wouldn't run a query like this?

```
MATCH (I:Interface {IfIPAddress:p.OrigIPAddress}), (I2:Interface {IfIPAddress:p.TermIPAddress})
MERGE (I)-[r:link]->(I2)
ON CREATE SET r = p
```

Run it on the transactional cypher endpoint, for instance with as many statements per transaction as there are iterations in your foreach loop.

Comment: Thanks. The reason why I am avoiding this query is because I have a lot of links to be created at a time. I have a map of arrays of props so wanted to create all the links using a single query instead of requesting the server everytime to create a link. The number of links to be created ranger from 10 K to 20 k

Comment: Have you tried it or are you just guessing? You can send an arbitrary number of statements in one request, and an arbitrary number of requests to be executed in one transaction. The graph operations are the same whether you create 20k relationships in one statement or in 20k statements. There will be some overhead on the wire, but as a compensation the query caching would probably be a lot better. See [transactional endpoint](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/milestone/rest-api-transactional.html) and [jdbc driver](http://www.neo4j.org/develop/tools/jdbc).